# sources.list in apt file not working

Tags: linux, kali-linux, repository

I'm using kali linux 2024.1
i had problem with sources.list repository and couldn't fix it
i thought if i delete the whole apt file and replace it again from kali packages in Gitlab but it didn't work it says apt.conf is missing
i try to extract kali iso image and install apt.deb files using dpkg -i 
it worked with apt.conf missing problem
then i added sources.list and sources.list.d manually
i tried again sudo apt update, sudo apt-get update it says

```
GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-experimental InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

please help i have big problem

Comment: I recommend you reinstall from scratch. Kali isn't intended for desktop use to begin with so you shouldn't lose much of import. And if you were using Kali as your desktop system despite being a beginner then I urge you to try another distro, *any* other distro, to learn linux.

Answer (score 0):

Open up console and run these two commands:

```bash
sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
sudo gpg -a --export ED444FF07D8D0BF6 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Taken and modified from:

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18079-Public-key-error

Comment: Alternately, don't, because 1) that only solves half the problem and 2) `apt-key` is being deprecated.